# magento 2.4.6 styles overide issue

Tags: css, less, magento2

I have a magento 2.4 theme which defines its css using a styles-m.less file

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/styles-m.less
```

There is also a source subdirectory, with different .less files per module :
ex:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/home/_styles.less
```

ISSUE :

In some frontend pages (ex customer account), the generated styles-m.css is overiden by styles-l.css which seems to be generated by magento original blank theme.

I then tried:

- copying original styles-l.less from blank theme to

  app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/styles-l.less
- add custom _module.less file in

  app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/customer/_module.less
- modify the styles-l.less file to import my custom customer/_module.less file
- setup:static-content:deploy -f, flush magento cache

But it does not work. styles-l.css seems to be the same as before.

here is my custom styles-l.less file.
What did I miss ?

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

//
//  Blank theme desktop styles
//  _____________________________________________

//  These desktop styles are additional to mobile

//
//  Global lib + theme styles
//  ---------------------------------------------

@import '_styles.less';

//
//  Magento Import instructions
//  ---------------------------------------------

//@magento_import 'source/_module.less'; // Theme modules
//@magento_import 'source/_widgets.less'; // Theme widgets

//
//  Media queries collector
//  ---------------------------------------------

@import 'source/lib/_responsive.less';

@media-target: 'desktop'; // Sets target device for this file
@media-common: false; // Sets not to output common styles

//
//  Global variables override
//  ---------------------------------------------

@import 'source/_theme.less';

//
//  Extend for minor customisation
//  ---------------------------------------------

//@magento_import 'source/_extend.less';
@import 'source/customer/_module.less';
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER :

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- Clear cache